# how to find unique rows in a large file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting, awk

I have a large file (4 billion rows) each row contains one word. I want to find list of the unique words and the corresponding counts.

I tried:

`sort largefile |uniq -c >outfile`

but it is still running and no output.

then I tried:

`awk '!arr[$1]++' largefile >outfile`

but it does not not print the counts. How can I use awk to print the counts as well? or any other alternative approach that can handle large files.

edit: There is about 17 million unique words in the file.

Comment: cat largefile | awk '{printf("%s %d\n",$1,arr[$1]++)}' | sort -n

Comment: This is called "having bad data," or possibly "misusing a ridiculous data structure." If you have 4 billion of anything, flat files are probably the wrong way to go if you're trying to optimize for speed.

Comment: If you tell `sort` to use as much RAM as you can spare, it will run a lot, lot faster. For example `sort -S 8G ...` if you're running on a 64-bit system with more than 8G of RAM (and your sort is a 64-bit executable)

Comment: Sometimes you can do a `sort -u` to handle larger files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large are the files? how many unique words are you expecting? In most cases your `sort | uniq` solution is a good start, but obviously if the files are too big it's not good. A Perl script that saves each word in a hash might work for you.

This is untested and from memory, so it may have a bunch of errors...

```
my %words = ();
open(IN, "<", "yourfile") or die "Arrgghh file didn't open: $!";
while(<IN>) {
    chomp;
    $words{$_}++;
}
close(IN);
for my $k in (keys %words) {
    print "$k $words{$k}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is ok. Try just doing:

```
sort largefile | uniq -c
```

it will take some time.

Answer (score 3):

`uniq` is the way to go but 4 billion rows are just a lot of rows. If you need the information frequently I would setup a database and import the rows. This will speedup index based queries. But however, 4 billion rows are a lot of rows

Answer (score 2):

Preprocess the files using split -l 1000000 , to split the file into 40 1,000,000 line files , sort them using sort -u . merge them back into one big file , give that to sort -u again.

```
## if you use just this, you need gawk 4.1
#
gawk '{key[$0]++;} END { for( word in key ) { print key[word] "\t" word }}' bigfile


cd to directory with bigfile
split -l 1000000 bigfile aa, small    ## makes smallaa, smallab, etc.

for files in small*
do
  echo "Sorting file $files"
  sort -u $files -o $files.srt
done

sort -m *.srt -o bigagain
sort -u bigagain > smallish

now have words but no counts.
gawk '{key[$0]++;}' smallish bigfile   # or better yet
```

Comment: dīvide et īmpera